# LineEdit box in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

When I press the Key Enter in the lineEdit box performs both function enter_LineEdit() and function click_Edit(). Why does it perform function click_Edit()? It must not!

I would like someone to explain to me why does it work this way?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QDialog,QHBoxLayout,QLabel,QWidget,QLineEdit
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,600,400)
        self.CreateBtn()
        self.show()

    def CreateBtn(self):
        button = QPushButton("Second Window", self)
        button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30,100,200,80))
        button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(70,70))
        button.clicked.connect(self.SecWin)

    def SecWin(self):
        self.d = SecondWindow()
        self.d.Create_SecWin()
        self.d.Create_Object()
        self.d.Create_Layout()


class SecondWindow(QDialog):

    def Create_SecWin(self):
        self.setGeometry(600,360,400,100)
        self.show()

    def Create_Object(self):
        self.btnEdit = QPushButton("Edit",self)
        self.btnEdit.clicked.connect(self.click_Edit)
        self.labelSearch = QLabel("Search:",self)
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.enter_LineEdit)

    def Create_Layout(self):
        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1.addWidget(self.btnEdit)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.labelSearch)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.setLayout(hbox1)

    def click_Edit(self):
        print("Philip")

    def enter_LineEdit(self):
        print("Karl")



App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you review the docs of the [autoDefault](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) property of QPushButton:

> This property holds whether the push button is an auto default button
>
> If this property is set to true then the push button is an auto
>   default button.
>
> In some GUI styles a default button is drawn with an extra frame
>   around it, up to 3 pixels or more. Qt automatically keeps this space
>   free around auto-default buttons, i.e., auto-default buttons may have
>   a slightly larger size hint.
>
> **This property's default is true for buttons that have a QDialog
>   parent; otherwise it defaults to false.**
>
> See the default property for details of how default and auto-default
>   interact.

And also from the [default](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) property:

> [...]
>
> A button with this property set to true (i.e., the dialog's default
>   button,) will automatically be pressed when the user presses enter,
>   with one exception: if an autoDefault button currently has focus, the
>   autoDefault button is pressed. **When the dialog has autoDefault buttons
>   but no default button, pressing enter will press either the
>   autoDefault button that currently has focus, or if no button has
>   focus, the next autoDefault button in the focus chain**.
>
> [...]

That is, some of the QPushButtons will be pressed when the enter key is pressed in a QDialog since all QPushButtons have the autoDefault property in True, so the solution is to set it to False:

```
self.btnEdit = QPushButton("Edit", self)
self.btnEdit.setAutoDefault(False)
```

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc, it solved my problem perfectly. I can't understand this 'AutoDefault', but that's okay too.